# Vlcj fails to open the mrl

Tags: java, video-streaming, vlcj

I'm using vlcj for streaming live video from an ip camera into my java application.
The problem is that whenever I try using a lan address to obtain the stream the code fails to open the socket.

The error is as follows:

```
[01ac1028] access_http access error: cannot connect to 192.168.19.14:81
[01ac1028] access_mms access error: cannot connect to 192.168.19.14:81
[01adb550] main input error: open of `http://@192.168.19.14:81' failed
[01adb550] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[01adb550] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'http://@192.168.19.14:81'.
```

Check the log for details.

Can anyone guide me about how to remove these errors?

Comment: Have you tested the mrl using VLC media player just to make sure it works?

Comment: In addition to that, have you checked it's not a firewall issue (switch your firewall off and try again?)

Answer (score 0):

```
mediaPlayer.playMedia("dshow://", 
                    ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,fps=15,scale=1,width=1280,height=800,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://@:5555/demo}",
                      ":no-sout-rtp-sap", 
                     ":no-sout-standard-sap", 
                      ":sout-all", 
                      ":sout-keep");
```

use this..

Answer (score 0):

Two things might be going wrong there:

- Make sure you have the firewall stuff worked out [Firewall Enabling for VLC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Scp5--4YYnI)
- Make sure the IP Camera is active & available for communication (My case this was the issue),
  Here is the log[image: Log from VLC player for my case]